# Python and factorial

Tags: python, python-2.7, factorial

I was trying to print a factorial for a number and I am wondering what's going wrong when I am doing something instead of

`fact *= j+1`

I always get 0 as output when I try out the commented part. What's the reason for that, aren't they supposed to mean the same thing? OR am I going wrong in the syntax?

```
test = int(raw_input())
while test:
    test = test-1
    num = int(raw_input())
    fact = 1
    for j in range(num):       
        fact *= j+1             # fact *= j 
                                # j += 1
    print fact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becasue 0 times any number is zero.

```
>>> 0 * 1
0
>>> 0 * 1 * 2 * 3
0
```

[`range(num)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returns list of numbers between 0 and `num-1`:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want to exclude 0, you need to use `range(1, n)`:

```
>>> range(1, 5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

BTW, in the standard library, there is [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.factorial):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.factorial(4)
24
```

Answer (score 1):

`range(num)` returns `[0, 1, ... , num-1]`

so:

```
fact *= j
j += 1
```

multiplied 0 at first step

while:

```
fact *= j+1
```

started with j+1

Answer (score 0):

you can use factorial function of python eg:-

import math

math.factorial(number) #this will return the factorial of a number